# Error de conexión a base datos al iniciar el servidor por primera vez

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy haciendo mi primera práctica de Ruby on Rails y todo iba bien hasta que he intentado ejecutar el servidor por primera vez . En la línea de comandos ( desde el directorio raíz de mi proyecto ) escribi *rails server* y luego en el navegar voy a localhost:3000 y me sale este mensaje de error : 
"Mysql2::Error
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Según las instrucciones dice que debo comentar (#) la " #database : simpe_cms_development" en el archivo database.yml lo cual hice. Hay 3 partes donde se configura las *database*: defaul, production y test. Comente la default y trate de iniciar el servidor con el mismo arror. Despues comente las otras 2 *database* en database.yml y mismo error.

También dice que debo proporcionar la contraseña que me puse al instalar msql . He establecido la contraseña en database.yml archivo como "boots"

```
    username: root
    password: boots
    host: localhost
```

Pero aun tengo el mismo problema: mismo error: 
"Mysql2::Error
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" La contraseña 'boots' es correcta. Alguien sabra que hacer en este caso?

Answer (score 1):

Checa el accesso en tu `DATABASE.YML`
el error tu contraseña mal, las causas

1 - el socket: `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`   (SI es mac)

2- el puerto 
  `port:   3306` (este por default si no checa cual es tu puerto por default en tu administrador de base de datos `phpmyadmin`)

Answer (score 1):

Verifica que tienes todo configurado en `config/database.yml`: `user, password, port, etc`.

Answer (score 0):

Has probado a conectarte desde un cliente sql?
Prueba con http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net u otro de tu preferencia

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje te indica que el acceso a la base de datos con el usuario y contraseña provista no es correcta.

Por lo que deberías validar :

Que el cliente de base de datos se encuentre activo y los accesos sean correctos ( puedes validar esto mediante una conexión via consola )

Según noto por tu pregunta al parecer nunca hiciste la conexión anteriormente a la creacion de la aplicación y puede que estés confundiendo que al definir los accesos en el database.yml la base de datos es quien la adopta y en realidad funciona de modo inverso, primero configuras la base de datos, pruebas que esta lista para escuchar conexiones y luego usas esas credenciales en la aplicación rails.